# inserting data from multiple table

Tags: mysql, sql-insert

I currently have two tables which they do not have anything in common, and I would like to get data from both tables and insert it into the 3rd table.

### table A

> CustomerId | CustomerName | PhoneNumber

### table B

> ProductId | ProductName | priceA | PriceB | PriceC

### table C

> id | customerID | productID

The problem now is that whenever I insert a new product (table B), I would like to have it assign to each customer (table A)

So let says

### table A

```
  c1  |  aa  |  1234 
  c2  |  bb  |  3456  
  c3  |  cc  |  3123
```

### and table B

```
  p1  |  candy  |  1.1  |  1.2  |  1.3
  p2  |  bag  |  5.5  |  5.6  |  5.7
  p3  |  key  |  3.3  |  3.1  |  3.5
```

and I would like it to have each customer assigned to all products like the following:

### table C

```
  1  |  c1  |  p1  
  2  |  c1  |  p2  
  3  |  c1  |  p3
  4  |  c2  |  p1  
  5  |  c2  |  p2
  6  |  c2  |  p3
  7  |  c3  |  p1
  8  |  c3  |  p2
  9  |  c3  |  p3
```

can I please get any suggestion of how i should do this. my original thought was to use JOIN, but there is nothing in common that I can join, is there a better and faster way to do this?

Comment: How about using CARTESIAN JOIN or the CROSS JOIN?

Answer (score 1):

The above scenario is perfectly matched for a cross join.

This is how cross join works:
[image: Cross Join in MySQL]

Now the below line of query is going to select the required result set that is to be inserted to the table C.

```
SELECT      A.customer_id, B.product_id
FROM        A
CROSS JOIN  B
```

Just insert the result set obtained by the above query:

```
INSERT INTO C
SELECT      A.customer_id, B.product_id
FROM        A
CROSS JOIN  B
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a perfect fit for a `cross join` - a join without a condition, that matches every row of one table to every row on the other:

```
INSERT TO c (customer_id, product_id) -- Assuming c.id is auto incremented...
SELECT      a.customer_id, b.product_id
FROM        a
CROSS JOIN  b
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess you could add customers and/or products at any time. An initial load using a cross join would be useful. As new customers or products are onboarded then an insert..on duplicate key (or insert..ignore if you prefer) may be sufficient to update table c. If that's too slow you might consider truncating table c before doing a full load (using cross join) or adding triggers to table a and table b to do the job. https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/insert-on-duplicate.html You will need to ensure you have a key to be checked so table c should have a unique key on customerID,productID